# Reverse an enum in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the next code:

```js
enum MyEnum {
  Colors = 'AreColors',
  Cars = 'AreCars',
}

const menuTitle = ((obj: MyEnum) => {
  const newObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((x) => {
    newObj[obj[x]] = x;
  });
  return newObj;
});
```

Here i want to change the enum keys in place of enum values.
Doing this i get `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'` here `newObj[obj[x]] = x;`.
Why the issue appears and how to solve?

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues of your code:

1. If you want to invert the key-value pairs of the enum by passing in `MyEnum` as the object, then you need to use `obj: typeof MyEnum`. This is assuming you want to use `menuTitle(MyEnum)` to perform the inversion.
2. `Object.keys(obj)` will return an array of strings and this causes indexing issues with your enum. If you cast it to an array of `keyof typeof MyEnum` then it will work.

Improved code:

```
enum MyEnum {
  Colors = 'AreColors',
  Cars = 'AreCars',
}

const menuTitle = ((obj: typeof MyEnum) => {
  const newObj: { [key in MyEnum]?: keyof typeof MyEnum } = {};
  (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof typeof MyEnum>).forEach((x) => {
    newObj[obj[x]] = x;
  });
  return newObj;
});

console.log(menuTitle(MyEnum));
```

See proof-of-concept example on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKClAwgewDY4BOAzlALxQDkAgocLgSZQDQbYCGJ5Vt9nxLNAF80aAMY4QxAC5QIoMABUAltLzBuACk04ARgCsAXFGlwADsBwAzWImQBKcgD4o6TBKmyQwAO4B5A2MUKABtAGtgOChlEFskSABdAH5jCLhrE3NLG3h46CFuFCEAbjZNAP1gMWkAOjTiHQNHdlJaQnY4AB40jNMLDNzkJ3saqyIEdjEAC20AD0cyFzdMKG9-AxC9fRDZhITuWdLMIXsjqDppMEJYtYrSk9LxSWJ8YBqCAHNNeXAVNWBNINIPZTkA).